# How can I override react-router-dom Link component back link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

For what it's worth this is for react-router-dom v5.2.0.

I used to be able to easily override the back button link with the following code:

```js
const MyLink = () => ({
    <Link
        to={{
            pathname: 'go-somewhere',
            state: { previousPath: 'override-previous-path'
        }}
    >
        Go Somewhere
    </Link>
})
```

By setting `previousPath` to whatever I would like to override to, it would override whatever I had visited previously. However, now that simply seemed to have stopped working one day.

Looking at the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) the `to` prop does not seem to have been changed, but the location has. Is it the `previousPath` state property that is incorrect?

Is there still a way to override the back link through the Link component?

Comment: So... you want to hack the `.goBack()` in order to take the user to the "previousPath" that you want?

Comment: @Tom Pretty much. If possible, through the Link component from react-router-dom. Keep in mind that the reason for this is due to leveraging legacy code, that I am told at one point worked.

Comment: I did some digging and I didn't find how the `previousPath` on the `state` property could indicate the wish to replace the current entry in the history stack. Are you missing something? Maybe you are getting the `previousPath` through the `location`, like: `location.state.previousPath` in order to know where you want to go back? Do you have any reference to that specific feature in the documentation? I went through the react-router-dom and history doc and didn't find anything

Comment: Unfortunately not, and have also dug in to react-router-dom and history docs and couldn't find anything either. Unfortunately all I have is the word of the people who previously worked on this who swear it once worked, but not so sure about it anymore.

Comment: but ignoring the Link component, is there no othert way to override the previousPath through some other way?

Comment: yes, I found an alternative solution. I'll leave you the answer down here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what we have discussed in the question comments, it doesn't seem possible to replace the current entry in the history stack by simply setting a `previousPath` on the `state` property (at least in react-router-dom v5.2.0).

An alternative solution could be something like this:

```
import { useHistory, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const MyLink = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <Link to="go-somewhere" onClick={() => history.replace("override-previous-path")}>
      Go Somewhere
    </Link>
  );
};
```

This will take the user to where you want him to go and it will replace the current entry in the history stack with the route that you want. So... if a `.goBack()` or a `.go(-1)` is executed, it will take the user "back" to where you wanted instead of the previous page.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work. It just takes me to `override-previous-path` as opposed to `go-somewhere`

Comment: Try this: https://codesandbox.io/s/linkcomponent-tbxbs and tell me if the behavior is correct or not

Comment: Yup, that behaviour is indeed correct.
However, for whatever reason, on my app if I use `history.replace('/something')` it immediately redirects me to `/something` instead of going to the link on `to`. Maybe there is something else unrelated going on here, will have to do more digging. But as far as this thread is concerned, this indeed answers my question. Thank you so much for all your help.